# String Concatenation in Purescript

Tags: string, import, module, functional-programming, purescript

Playing with purescript and running into an odd problem with string concatenation. I've loaded and imported the `Prelude`, `Data.List`, `Data.Maybe`, and `Data.String` (also, tried importing `Data.Array`) but the PSCi still doesn't recognize `(++)`. This would suggest that either, `(++)` is not contained in any of my imported modules (in which case a pointer to the appropriate module(s) to import would be appreciated), or there was some weird problem when I installed purescript and set my enviornment. I find the latter unlikely but hey I'll keep my considerations open.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: Did you try using `<>`? As in, `"hello, " <> name <> "!"` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Newer versions of PureScript (since 0.9 I think) have abandoned `++` in favor of `<>`. That operator should work out of the box, since it is contained in [purescript-prelude](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/1.0.1/docs/Data.Semigroup#v:(%3C%3E)).

Thanks @gb. for the clarification. Edited the incorrect part of my answer.

Comment: Almost right! `(++)` and `(<>)` were both aliases for `Semigroup`'s `append`, but we decided to do away with having multiple operators for the same thing. `(<>)` came out as the favourite in the GitHub issue for it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @gb. which github issue?

Comment: @Ron I had to do some excavating, at one point it did seem like `(++)` was favoured: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/issues/40, but eventually I found this: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/pull/52#issuecomment-172279525 - so looks like I wasn't quite right, in that it happened on IRC rather than in a GH issue.

Comment: Thanks @gb.
Still wondering how did `(<>)` won. Even the PR initially picked `(++)` -- “`(<>)` was dropped in favour of `(++)` ... reasons: `(++)` is more suggestive of appending when dealing with things like strings, arrays. Almost all other operators based around `(<>)` are for functorial types.”   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯